# Javascript filters, how to make each of them function independently?

Tags: javascript, jquery, web, filtering

https://www.australianathleticscalendar.com.au/

This website originally had one filter, but I added another one, wanting each of them to work independently (i.e. filter by category (events), and also filter by states).

It seems it's still acting as one filter, as in I can only select one variable between the two filters set up. How can I adjust the functions so each filter operates independently?

```
    function loadCategories() {
    fetch(projectUrl + '/categories')
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then(json => {
        this.categories = json.categories;
        drawCategories();
    })
}

function loadStates() {
    fetch(projectUrl + '/states')
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then(json => {
        this.states = json.states;
        drawStates();
    })
}

function drawProducts(products) {
    var template = Handlebars.compile(document.getElementById("products-template").innerHTML);
    document.getElementById('products-container').innerHTML = template({
        title: this.title,
        titleStates:this.titleStates,
        products: products  
    });
}

function drawCategories() {
    var template = Handlebars.compile(document.getElementById("menu-template").innerHTML);
    console.log('draw ', this.products);
    document.getElementById('menu-container').innerHTML = template(this.categories);
}

function drawStates() {
    var template = Handlebars.compile(document.getElementById("menu-template-2").innerHTML);
    console.log('draw ', this.products);
    document.getElementById('menu-container-states').innerHTML = template(this.states);
}

function showAllProducts() {
    this.title = "All Events";
    drawProducts(this.products);
}

function showAllProducts() {
    this.titleStates = "All States";
    drawProducts(this.products);
}

function showCategory(category) {
    this.title = category;
    let filteredProducts = this.products.filter(product => {
        return product.category.toLowerCase().includes(category.toLowerCase());
    }); 
    drawProducts(filteredProducts);
}


function showState(state) {
    this.titleStates = state;
    let filteredProducts = this.products.filter(product => {
        return product.state.toLowerCase().includes(state.toLowerCase());
    }); 
    drawProducts(filteredProducts);
}
```

They are called in the menu, here are the two filters:

```
      <!-- Categories/events filter -->
<div class="container">
    <script id="menu-template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
            
                <ul class="navbar-nav">
                    {{#each this as |category|}}
                        <li class="nav-item"></li>
                            <a class="nav-link" href="#" onclick="showCategory('{{category.name}}');">{{category.name}}</a>
                        </li>
                    {{/each}}
                    <!-- <a id="all-events" href="#" onclick="showAllProducts();">All Events</a> -->
                    <a class="navbar-brand hover-color" href="#" onclick="showAllProducts();">All Events</a>
                </ul>
                
                <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto"></ul>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        
                    </li>
                </ul>

        </div>
    </script>
</div>

<!-- States filter -->
<div class="container">
    <script id="menu-template-2" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
            
                <ul class="navbar-nav">
                    {{#each this as |state|}}
                        <li class="nav-item"></li>
                            <a class="nav-link" href="#" onclick="showState('{{state.name}}');">{{state.name}}</a>
                        </li>
                    {{/each}}
                    <!-- <a id="all-events" href="#" onclick="showAllProducts();">All Events</a> -->
                    <a class="navbar-brand hover-color" href="#" onclick="showAllProducts();">All States</a>
                </ul>
                
                <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto"></ul>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        
                    </li>
                </ul>

        </div>
    </script>
</div>
```

Comment: Javascript has nothing to do with java. Please remove the java tag.

Comment: Cannot open your link. Please add the part where you call these functions.

Comment: @trincot I added the html where they are called. You should be able to view the site here: https://www.australianathleticscalendar.com.au/

Comment: You have twice the function `showAllProducts`: the first one will be overwritten by the second. Is this a copy/paste error? The question will get more specific attention if you tag this question with handlebars, as your code depends on it.

Comment: I need a showAllCategories which resets the Categories filter, and a showAllStates which resets the States filter, however, I can't figure out how to make them operate separately

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you have a duplicate function `showAllProducts`, which you have also linked to two different buttons. I suppose you intended to have two different functions, one for each "All" button, so add a function called `showAllEvents` and another `showAllStates`, and reference those as button handlers.

On the question: you should move the filtering to one function which will take the two filters into account. You could use `this.title` and `this.titleState` to perform the filtering, making sure you treat the "All" case correctly.

So the filtering functions, which you bind to your HTML, should become:

```
function showAllProducts() {
    this.title = "All Events";
    this.titleStates = "All States";
    drawProducts();
}

function showAllEvents() {
    this.title = "All Events";
    drawProducts();
}

function showAllStates() {
    this.titleStates = "All States";
    drawProducts();
}

function showCategory(category) {
    this.title = category;
    drawProducts();
}

function showState(state) {
    this.titleStates = state;
    drawProducts();
}
```

Note the new functions, so make sure you reference them in your HTML. Secondly, I removed the filtering from these functions, as I propose to do that in `drawProducts`. And that function will take no arguments now:

```
function drawProducts() { // remove argument; extend with filtering
    var template = Handlebars.compile(document.getElementById("products-template").innerHTML);
    // Perform filtering here:
    var filteredProducts = this.products.filter(product => {
        return (this.title.slice(0, 4) === "All " || product.category.toLowerCase().includes(this.title.toLowerCase()))
            && (this.titleState.slice(0, 4) === "All " || product.state.toLowerCase().includes(this.titleState.toLowerCase());
    });
    document.getElementById('products-container').innerHTML = template({
        title: this.title,
        titleStates: this.titleStates,
        products: filteredProducts // <--  
    });
}
```

Comment: I still seem to be getting an error on this function:

`function loadProducts() {
 fetch(projectUrl + '/products')
 .then((response) => response.json())
 .then(json => {
  this.products = json.products;
  showAllProducts();
 });
}`

Comment: So think about that. Do you understand why? I added a definition for `showAllProducts` which is like a combination of the other two `ShowAllXX` that I introduced. Don't forget to bind the two "All" buttons to those two new functions.

Comment: It works! I pushed it live for you to see: https://www.australianathleticscalendar.com.au/

I honestly cannot thank you enough for your help.

Comment: Done, thanks again. I'm curious, why do you go to so much effort to help people, what do you gain?

Comment: I love programming, and the challenge. By doing this I also learn new things from what I read in other answers. It is a hobby.

Comment: One more question if you don't mind. Is there any way I can continue making the state filter work as is, however whilst excluding the `{{product.state}}` from the front-end? In other words, simply keep it functioning as is, but remove the 'QLD', NSW' etc from view

Comment: Where is this `{{product.state}}`?

Comment: `<h2 class="m-0 gradient-text">{{product.shortDescription}}, {{product.location}}, {{product.state}}</h2>` It's in the title of each competition. But the {{product.location}} already tells the user where it's located (Which city). The purpose of the state tag is simply for the filtering

Comment: So you want to no longer show the state at the end of each line? [Are you sure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_the_most_common_U.S._place_names)? It seems still relevant when there is no filter on state... If you want this, just remove it from the `h2` tag you shared above.

Comment: That worked, I thought it'd need to be included in the `h2` tag for the function to work, but it doesn't. The 'city' already tells the user the location, so it's not necessary for it to be in the title. It's necessary purely for filtering. With the way the products function is currently written, would putting in a search function for the competition title (`shortDescription`) be possible?

Comment: Yes, you can create the corresponding functions, introducing yet another `titleDescription` property, which you use in the `filter` logic. My point about the city/state, is that there are several cities that exist in multiple states, so showing the state removes this potential ambiguity. See [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_the_most_common_U.S._place_names)

Comment: One more question. The CSS focus selector only allows you to focus on one element at a time. Is there a way to use javascript to add styling to the selected filter: https://www.australianathleticscalendar.com.au/ So that when I select, say 100m and 'QLD', it will have styling on both at once

Comment: Sure, define a CSS class for the styling you want, and then apply it (and take it away) through JavaScript. Check out the classList property and its methods.

Comment: I tried out the classList for the :focus selector but couldn't quite work out a solution. Did a post here if you were interested: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65857843/replicate-css-focus-selector-for-multiple-elements-using-javascript